# Benchmarking System performance of Python System

Tags: python, linux, benchmarking, inotify

I'm looking at using inotify to watch about 200,000 directories for new files. On creation, the script watching will process the file and then it will be removed. Because it is part of a more compex system with many processes, I want to benchmark this and get system performance statistics on cpu, memory, disk, etc while the tests are run.

I'm planning on running the inotify script as a daemon and having a second script generating test files in several of the directories (randomly selected before the test).

I'm after suggestions for the best way to benchmark the performance of something like this, especially the impact it has on the Linux server it's running on.

Answer (score 1):

I would try and remove as many other processes as possible in order to get a repeatable benchmark.  For example, I would set up a separate, dedicated server with an NFS mount to the directories.  This server would only run inotify and the Python script.  For simple server measurements, I would use `top` or `ps` to monitor CPU and memory.

The real test is how quickly your script "drains" the directories, which depends entirely on your process.  You could profile the script and see where it's spending the time.

Comment: I had been thinking of something like this, your answer helps validate that. I think `dstat` would be better than `top`. `dstat` can output to a file and you can then convert it to a graph. I'm not sure how `ps` would help monitor the system performance? Can you explain more on that? I use it for checking individual processes.

Comment: @EdwardWilliams: `ps` would show a status of 'D' if the process is waiting on disk I/O (or swapping), which is likely if your process is scanning a directory.  It can also show % CPU and % Memory being used by your process.  If your process is not disk-bound and the % numbers are relatively low (say, under 50%), then your process is keeping up with the load.  If the status is 'R' then it's running your code to try and keep up.  The status should be 'S' as it "sleeps" while waiting for another file.  I haven't used `dstat` before.